# Deploying contract byte code via assembly

Tags: solidity, evm, bytecode

I'm trying to write a smart contract which will deploy byte code using assembly op_code `create`. I'm following [this post](https://blog.aragon.one/advanced-solidity-code-deployment-techniques-dc032665f434).

But when I call `deployCode` function I got nothing. Ropsten etherscan tells me that I've **exceeded gas limit**.
See [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x394e4191e0ca330d1d0dbb78ea7de96ad8ca1707). But this contract costs **only 1-2 millions of gas.**

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to deploy ASCII, not bytecode.

You can have a look at what your contract *actually* tried to create by checking the parity trace of the transaction: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x068629bdf944db9a7458fe4b723f1b26916d8d15cf3ff01afec67ac7cca22e55&type=parity

If you run `Web3.utils.toAscii` on the code you were deploying it comes out to:

(Note, you're missing a library anyway)

`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__Common________________________________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`